# Created Migration: 2014_06_17_084521_create_users_table - cant find migration?

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm on shared hosting with SSH tunnel access and stood in the root of my Laravel install. If I run a migration from bash:

```
$ /usr/bin/php-5.4 artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create=users
Created Migration: 2014_06_17_084521_create_users_table
Generating optimized class loader
```

artisan is reporting success - only I cant see the migration in '/app/database/migrations' or in the database? Anybody experienced this before?

Sure enough, through the shell and if I change directories `/var/sites/e/example.co.uk/bob/app/database/migrations`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 7423 458 Jun 16 15:52 2014_06_16_145039_create_users_table.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 7423 326 Jun 16 15:58 2014_06_16_145701_create_users_table.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 7423 458 Jun 16 16:26 2014_06_16_152433_create_users_table.php
```

I can see my migrations - in the shell or on the filesystem.

Comment: If you can see it through shell, it's most likely a chown issue. I have to chown `apache:apache` (in CentOS) or `nobody:nogroup` (in Ubuntu server) after creating files over artisan commands to make them editable through ftp etc.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that I am understanding your question correctly, you are creating the migration, it says success, but it's not appearing in the database/migrations directory when accessed over FTP or when viewing `ls` through bash?

If it was a privileges issue, you would still be able to see it from bash.

Are you certain you are in the correct root?
Does the database/migrations folder have an odd sticky bit set?

You might try resetting all privileges by running these commands at the root of your application.  You should change the `www-data` user and group to the appropriate user and group for your server's daemon. (This is default for Ubuntu)

```
chown -R www-data:www-data *;
find -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;
```

Comment: It was a misunderstanding on my part. I can now or could a couple of months ago see the migrations. Apologies.